# Does gcc have an -N option?

Tags: gcc, ld

In [*"Learning Linux Binary Analysis"* by Ryan "elfmaster" O'Neill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01891X7V0).

> Another neat trick that I just recently discovered during the 
>   construction of the Skeksi virus for 64-bit Linux is to merge the text and data segment into a single segment, that is, **read+write+execute (RWX)**, by using the `-N` option with gcc.

I don't see an `-N` option in `man gcc` nor in `gcc --help | grep '\-N'`? Was this option renamed?

Comment: `-N` appears to be an option to ld, the loader. `-N
       --omagic
           Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable.  Also, do not page-align the data segment, and disable linking against shared libraries.  If the output format
           supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the output as "OMAGIC". Note: Although a writable text section is allowed for PE-COFF targets, it does not conform to the format
           specification published by Microsoft.`

Comment: @wildplasser if you want to make it answer I'll accept it

Comment: The linker, you mean. You will pass it to GCC as `-Wl,N` or something...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, thanks, I added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-N` appears to be an option to (gnu)ld, the linker("loader")

From `man ld`:

> `-N` `--omagic`
>              Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable.  Also, do not page-align the data segment, and disable linking against
>   shared libraries.  If the output format
>              supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the output as "OMAGIC". Note: Although a writable text section is allowed for
>   PE-COFF targets, it does not conform to the format
>              specification published by Microsoft.

The`gcc` compiler-*driver* will pass options prepended with `-Wl,` to the loader, so your gcc-commandline will be something like:

```
gcc -Wl,-N -oher_options...`
```